# How do I determine the disk size of a SharePoint list?

Tags: sharepoint, moss, wss

I have a list with roughly 5500 items, and I would like to find out the size on disk.  Is there some way I can do this?  I don't mind running a query in the database, if necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you enable a site quota, an option under site settings appears called **Storage Space Allocation**.  When you go to set a quota in the Central Administration, the page will tell you what the current storage used is so you can have an idea before there.   Once you get to the **Storage Space Allocation** report, you can see the total size of a library.

Unfortunately, you can't get this report without turning on a site quota.

Comment: p.s. site quotas are a really good thing - it is amazing how fast unfettered users can upload documents.

Answer (score 8):

Navigate to http://[myapplication]/[mySitecollection]/_layouts/storman.aspx

This will list the Storage Space Allocation for the site collection.

Answer (score 3):

I could not get Tim Dobrinski's suggestion to work. This T-SQL query does not deal with everything, but gives a very good idea. Pop it into Excel, then add a column for "Size in MB" and add in a formula.

```
USE [WSS_Content]
GO

SELECT
       [dbo].[Webs].[FullUrl]
      ,[dbo].[Lists].[tp_Title] AS "ListName"
      ,[dbo].[Docs].[DirName]
      ,[dbo].[Docs].[LeafName]
      ,[dbo].[Docs].[Size]
      ,[dbo].[Docs].[MetaInfoSize]
      ,[dbo].[Docs].[Version]
      ,[dbo].[Docs].[TimeCreated]
      ,[dbo].[Docs].[TimeLastModified]
      ,[dbo].[Docs].[MetaInfoTimeLastModified]
      ,[dbo].[Docs].[CheckoutUserId]
      ,[dbo].[Docs].[CheckoutDate]
      ,[dbo].[Docs].[ExtensionForFile]

  FROM [WSS_Content].[dbo].[Docs]
  INNER JOIN [WSS_Content].[dbo].[Webs] ON [dbo].[Webs].[Id] = [dbo].[Docs].[WebId]
  INNER JOIN [WSS_Content].[dbo].[Lists] ON [dbo].[Lists].[tp_ID] = [dbo].[Docs].[ListId]

  WHERE [dbo].[Docs].[Size] > 0     
  AND ([dbo].[Docs].[LeafName] NOT LIKE '%.stp')   
  AND ([dbo].[Docs].[LeafName] NOT LIKE '%.aspx')
  AND ([dbo].[Docs].[LeafName] NOT LIKE '%.xfp')
  AND ([dbo].[Docs].[LeafName] NOT LIKE '%.dwp')
  AND ([dbo].[Docs].[LeafName] NOT LIKE '%template%')
  AND ([dbo].[Docs].[LeafName] NOT LIKE '%.inf')
  AND ([dbo].[Docs].[LeafName] NOT LIKE '%.css')
```

Comment: I used this but with a few tweaks. Since we have around a million items moving this to Excel and summing it there was out of the question. Instead I did a GROUP BY [dbo].[Lists].[tp_Title] and selected [dbo].[Lists].[tp_Title] AS "ListName", SUM([dbo].[Docs].[Size]/1024+[dbo].[Docs].[MetaInfoSize]/1024). This showed me how big each List was in KB. I then exported this to Excel and worked with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you save the list in question as a template to the file system, this should give you a rough idea of its size.  If you need to do this on a periodic basis this approach is not as useful.

Comment: This only works if the total size is less than 50mb.

Answer (score 1):

Site Settings -> Storage Metrics

You can see how much each object is consuming, click on **Lists** to see each individual list

You don't have to set a site quota

Sharepoint 2013

[image: Site settings]

Answer (score 0):

This is taken from SharePoint 2013:

```
USE [WSS_Content_Intranet]
GO

SELECT 
    (ISNULL(DocSizes,0) + ISNULL(UserDataSize,0)) As TotalSize, 
    nLists.tp_ID,
    nLists.tp_Title,
    nLists.tp_ItemCount,
    Webs.FullUrl
FROM
    Webs
INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT 
        ALAux.ItemCount as tp_ItemCount, 
        Lists.tp_Title, 
        Lists.tp_ID, 
        Lists.tp_WebID, 
        ALAux.Modified as tp_Modified, 
        Lists.tp_ServerTemplate, 
        Docs.DirName, 
        Docs.LeafName, 
        Lists.tp_ImageUrl
    FROM 
        Lists
    CROSS APPLY
        TVF_AllListsAux_NoLock_ListId(Lists.tp_SiteId, Lists.tp_ID) AS ALAux
    INNER JOIN 
        Docs
    ON 
        Lists.tp_RootFolder = Docs.Id AND 
        Lists.tp_WebId = Docs.WebId 
    WHERE 
        tp_BaseType <> 1 AND
        Lists.tp_SiteId = YOUR_SITE_ID
    ) As nLists
    ON
        Webs.Id = nLists.tp_WebId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (
        SELECT 
            (SUM(CAST((ISNULL(Docs.Size,0)) AS BIGINT))) As DocSizes, 
            Docs.ListId,
            Docs.SiteId
        FROM 
            Docs 
        WHERE
            Docs.Type = 0 AND SiteId = YOUR_SITE_ID
        GROUP BY
            Docs.ListId,Docs.SiteId
        ) As DocsInList
        ON
            DocsInList.ListId = nLists.tp_ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
            (
            SELECT 
                (SUM(CAST((ISNULL(tp_Size,0)) AS BIGINT))) As UserDataSize, 
                tp_ListId 
            FROM
                UserData 
            GROUP BY 
                UserData.tp_ListId
            ) AS UserDataInList
            ON
                UserDataInList.tp_ListId = DocsInList.ListId
ORDER BY TotalSize DESC
```

It returns all lists of all webs, summing the size of the items and the attached documents. Document libraries are not included, use this:

```
SELECT
    Lists.tp_Title,
    Lists.tp_ID as Id,
    SUM(Docs.Size/1024 + Docs.MetaInfoSize/1024)/1024 AS SizeMB,
    COUNT(*) as NumberOfFiles
FROM dbo.Docs
    INNER JOIN Webs ON Webs.Id = Docs.WebId
    INNER JOIN Lists ON Lists.tp_ID = Docs.ListId
WHERE Docs.Size > 0
GROUP BY Lists.tp_Title,Lists.tp_ID
```

Comment: Ack! Don't query the content DB directly!

Comment: The user wrote `I don't mind running a query in the database, if necessary.`

Answer (score 0):

As Hussein Nasser said in this thread. This still relevant for SharePoint 2016 and Sharepoint 2019 (on-premise checked)

Being site collection admin, I went to Site **Settings -> Storage Metrics** and bingo...

If you have multiple lists, then click on Lists hyperlink, it will give you details info for each list.

[image: How it looks]