# SharePoint List Size

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I would like to calculate the size of a SharePoint List programmatically, but there is no size property in the SPList and the SPListItem classes. How can I determine the size of a SharePoint list?

Comment: Potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936167/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-a-sharepoint-list

Comment: what do you mean by size? Physical size in bytes? Size in SPItem Count?